# Why is the error 'not enough input arguments' occuring

Tags: matlab

I was trying to simulate this piece of code as part of simulation when this error occured.I am not able to understand how num_cycles is calculated in the above code.The code is part of a set of equations governing the time delay required for gate signal for a mosfet

```
function [Tsa,Tsb]=gentimeseries(m1,tp,num_cycles)
num_angles=(360/5)+1;
ts=(tp/(num_angles*50));
ts
tsa=[];
tsb=[];
alpha1=0;
ta1=0;
tb1=0;
tsa=[tsa;[ta1,0]];
tsb=[tsb;[tb1,0]];
while alpha1<=360
    [wa,da,wb,db]=svp(m1,alpha1);
    da=da*ts/100;
    db=db*ts/100;
    wa=wa*ts/100;
    wb=wb*ts/100;
    i=1;


    while i<=50
        ta1=ta1+da;
        tsa=[tsa;[ta1,1]];
        ta1=ta1+wa;
        tsa=[tsa;[ta1,0]];
        ta1=ta1+da;
        tsa=[tsa;[ta1,0]];
        i=i+1;
    end

    i=1;
    while i<=50
        tb1=tb1+db;
        tsb=[tsb;[tb1,1]];
        tb1=tb1+wb;
        tsb=[tsb;[tb1,0]];
        tb1=tb1+db;
        tsb=[tsb;[tb1,0]];
        i=i+1;
    end
    alpha1=alpha1+5;
end
x=tsa(:,2);
y=tsa(:,1);
plot(y,x,'.')
Tsa=timeseries(tsa(:,2),tsa(:,1));
Tsb=timeseries(tsb(:,2),tsb(:,1));
n_cycle=1;
while n_cycle<=num_cycles
    tta=Tsa;
    tta.time=tta.time+ta1;
    Tsa=Tsa.append(tta);
    ttb=Tsb;
    ttb.time=ttb.time+tb1;
    Tsb=Tsb.append(ttb);
    ta1=ta1+ta1;
    tb1=tb1+tb1;
    n_cycle=n_cycle+1;
end
end
```

Comment: How are you calling this function (`gentimeseries`)? The input argument `num_cycles` is not computed, you have to provide it yourself when calling the function. If you don't pass it to the function, you would get the error that you mentioned in the title.

Comment: `num_cycles` is an input argument to the function. You need to pass it when you call the function. Type `[Tsa,Tsb]=gentimeseries(m1,tp,num_cycles)` in the MATLAB command line, filling the appropriate values for the three arguments between parentheses.